# iOS - how to perform sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, apple-cryptokit

Recently Apple with iOS 13 introduced CryptoKit which has a method sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement which generates a shared secret from key agreement between public and private keys. How can this be achieved in iOS 12 and below ?

iOS 13

```
import CryptoKit

let alicePrivateKey = P256.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let alicePublicKey = alicePrivateKey.publicKey

let eileenPrivateKey = P256.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let eileenPublicKey = eileenPrivateKey.publicKey

let shared1 = try alicePrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: eileenPublicKey)
let shared2 = try eileenPrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: alicePublicKey)

if shared1 == shared2 {
    print("shared keys are equal")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult from iOS which works fine without issues.
only thing to make sure is ecSecPrivateKey and ecSecPrivateKey below used should be in Seckey format and should work fine.

```
 guard let derivedData = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(
                ecSecPrivateKey,
                SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandard,
                ecSecPublicKey,
                parameters as CFDictionary,
                &error)
                else {
                return
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```swift
import CryptoKit
import Foundation

let bobsPrivateKey = P521.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let bobsPublicKey = bobsPrivateKey.publicKey

let alicesPrivateKey = P521.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let alicesPublicKey = alicesPrivateKey.publicKey

let shared1 = try alicesPrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: bobsPublicKey)
let shared2 = try bobsPrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: alicesPublicKey)

if shared1 == shared2 {
    print("shared keys are equal")
}
```

Comment: CryptoKit is iOS 13+, so this doesn't work